# Problemas con galeria en jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css3

Hola estoy haciendo una galería, que contiene información e imagen. Estas 6 columnas poseen contenido oculto que al clickear se expande y muestra la información de dicha ficha. A estas imágenes en su estado de reposo tienen un  efecto de hover donde contenido de texto se muestra por encima. Este contenido puede ser el mismo que iría dentro de dicha ficha cuando se expande. Ahora el problema surje cuando expando la imagen y el contenido de texto del hover se queda. como haría

```js
var $cont = document.querySelector('.cont');
var $elsArr = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.el'));
var $closeBtnsArr = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.el__close-btn'));

setTimeout(function() {
  $cont.classList.remove('s--inactive');
}, 200);

$elsArr.forEach(function($el) {
  $el.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (this.classList.contains('s--active')) return;
    $cont.classList.add('s--el-active');
    this.classList.add('s--active');
  });
});

$closeBtnsArr.forEach(function($btn) {
  $btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $cont.classList.remove('s--el-active');
    document.querySelector('.el.s--active').classList.remove('s--active');
  });
});
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #1f1f1f;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.cont{
      width: 1170px;
    margin: auto;
    height: 404px;
    position: relative;
}

.el {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 15.999%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #252525;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.7s, opacity 0.6s 0.7s, z-index 0s 1.3s, -webkit-transform 0.6s 0.7s;
  transition: width 0.7s, opacity 0.6s 0.7s, z-index 0s 1.3s, -webkit-transform 0.6s 0.7s;
  transition: transform 0.6s 0.7s, width 0.7s, opacity 0.6s 0.7s, z-index 0s 1.3s;
  transition: transform 0.6s 0.7s, width 0.7s, opacity 0.6s 0.7s, z-index 0s 1.3s, -webkit-transform 0.6s 0.7s;
  will-change: transform, width, opacity;
}
.el:not(.s--active) {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.el__overflow {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
.el__inner {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
  transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
  transition: transform 1s;
  transition: transform 1s, -webkit-transform 1s;

}
.el__preview-cont{
  z-index: 22;
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  width: 250px;
  height: 401px;
}
.el__content {
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.1s;
  transition: all 0.1s;
}
.el.s--active .el__content {
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s 1.4s;
  transition: all 0.5s 1.4s;
}
.imagen{
background-image: url('../salvapantallas.jpg');
width: 405px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: 403px;

}




 .snip1273 {
  font-family: 'Raleway', Arial, sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
  min-width: 403px;
  max-width: 403px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 16px;
}
 .snip1273 * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
}
 .snip1273 img {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
 .snip1273 figcaption {
  position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 187px;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 77px 20px 0px 20px;
}
 .snip1273 figcaption .flecha{
  margin-top: 49px;
}
 .snip1273 figcaption:before,
 .snip1273 figcaption:after {
  width: 1px;
  height: 0;
}
 .snip1273 figcaption:before {
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
 .snip1273 figcaption:after {
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
 .snip1273 span,
 .snip1273 p {
  line-height: 1.5em;
}
 .snip1273 span {
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 71px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'helvetica';
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0;
    height: 76px;
    display: block;
}
 .snip1273 p {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
}
 .snip1273 a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
 .snip1273:before,
 .snip1273:after,
 .snip1273 figcaption:before,
 .snip1273 figcaption:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  background-color: #ffffff;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
  opacity: 0.8;
}


.snip1273:hover img,
 .snip1273.hover img {
  opacity: 0.4;
}
 .snip1273:hover figcaption,
 .snip1273.hover figcaption {
  opacity: 1;
}

 .snip1273:hover:before,
  .snip1273.hover:before,
  .snip1273:hover:after,
  .snip1273.hover:after,
  .snip1273:hover figcaption:before,
  .snip1273.hover figcaption:before,
  .snip1273:hover figcaption:after,
  .snip1273.hover figcaption:after {
  opacity: 0.1;
}




.el__text .img {
    width: 403px;
    height: 402px;
    float: left;
}
.el__text .description{
    width: 765px;
    float: right;
    padding: 30px;
    height: 403px;
}
.el__text img{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 344px;
    min-width: 401px;
}
.el__close-btn {
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0s 0.45s;
  transition: all 0s 0.45s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.el.s--active .el__close-btn {
  z-index: 5;
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  -webkit-transition: all 0s 1.4s;
  transition: all 0s 1.4s;
}
.el__close-btn:before, .el__close-btn:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 8px;
  margin-top: -4px;
  background: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0s;
  transition: opacity 0s;
}
.el.s--active .el__close-btn:before, .el.s--active .el__close-btn:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
.el__close-btn:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translateX(100%);
          transform: rotate(45deg) translateX(100%);
}
.el.s--active .el__close-btn:before {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s 1.4s cubic-bezier(0.72, 0.09, 0.32, 1.57);
  transition: all 0.3s 1.4s cubic-bezier(0.72, 0.09, 0.32, 1.57);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translateX(0);
          transform: rotate(45deg) translateX(0);
}
.el__close-btn:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translateX(100%);
          transform: rotate(-45deg) translateX(100%);
}
.el.s--active .el__close-btn:after {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s 1.55s cubic-bezier(0.72, 0.09, 0.32, 1.57);
  transition: all 0.3s 1.55s cubic-bezier(0.72, 0.09, 0.32, 1.57);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translateX(0);
          transform: rotate(-45deg) translateX(0);
}

.el:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
          transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
.cont.s--el-active .el:nth-child(1):not(.s--active) {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.5) translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
          transform: scale(0.5) translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.95s, -webkit-transform 0.95s;
  transition: opacity 0.95s, -webkit-transform 0.95s;
  transition: transform 0.95s, opacity 0.95s;
  transition: transform 0.95s, opacity 0.95s, -webkit-transform 0.95s;
}
.el:nth-child(1) .el__inner {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
          transition-delay: 0s;

}
.el:nth-child(1) .el__bg {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
}
.el:nth-child(1) .el__inner:before {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
          transition-delay: 0s;
  background-image: url("../salvapantallas.jpg");
}
.el:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(105.20833%, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(105.20833%, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 155.20833% 50%;
          transform-origin: 155.20833% 50%;
}
.cont.s--el-active .el:nth-child(2):not(.s--active) {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.5) translate3d(105.20833%, 0, 0);
          transform: scale(0.5) translate3d(105.20833%, 0, 0);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.95s, -webkit-transform 0.95s;
  transition: opacity 0.95s, -webkit-transform 0.95s;
  transition: transform 0.95s, opacity 0.95s;
  transition: transform 0.95s, opacity 0.95s, -webkit-transform 0.95s;
}
.el:nth-child(2) .el__inner {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s;
          transition-delay: 0.1s;
}
.el:nth-child(2) .el__bg {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-19.2%, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(-19.2%, 0, 0);
}
.el:nth-child(2) .el__bg:before {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s;
          transition-delay: 0.1s;
  background-image: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/142996/onepgscr-4.jpg");
}
.el:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(210.41667%, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(210.41667%, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 260.41667% 50%;
          transform-origin: 260.41667% 50%;
}
.cont.s--el-active .el:nth-child(3):not(.s--active) {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.5) translate3d(210.41667%, 0, 0);
          transform: scale(0.5) translate3d(210.41667%, 0, 0);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.95s, -webkit-transform 0.95s;
  transition: opacity 0.95s, -webkit-transform 0.95s;
  transition: transform 0.95s, opacity 0.95s;
  transition: transform 0.95s, opacity 0.95s, -webkit-transform 0.95s;
}
.el:nth-child(3) .el__inner {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
          transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
.el:nth-child(3) .el__bg {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-38.4%, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(-38.4%, 0, 0);
}
.el:nth-child(3) .el__bg:before {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
          transition-delay: 0.2s;
  background-image: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/142996/onepgscr-5.jpg");
}
.el:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(315.625%, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(315.625%, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 365.625% 50%;
          transform-origin: 365.625% 50%;
}
.cont.s--el-active .el:nth-child(4):not(.s--active) {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.5) translate3d(315.625%, 0, 0);
          transform: scale(0.5) translate3d(315.625%, 0, 0);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.95s, -webkit-transform 0.95s;
  transition: opacity 0.95s, -webkit-transform 0.95s;
  transition: transform 0.95s, opacity 0.95s;
  transition: transform 0.95s, opacity 0.95s, -webkit-transform 0.95s;
}
.el:nth-child(4) .el__inner {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s;
          transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
.el:nth-child(4) .el__bg {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-57.6%, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(-57.6%, 0, 0);
}
.el:nth-child(4) .el__bg:before {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s;
          transition-delay: 0.3s;
  background-image: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/142996/onepgscr-6.jpg");
}
.el:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(420.83333%, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(420.83333%, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 470.83333% 50%;
          transform-origin: 470.83333% 50%;
}


.el:nth-child(6) {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(527%, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(527%, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 527% 50%;
          transform-origin: 527% 50%;
}
.cont.s--el-active .el:nth-child(6):not(.s--active) {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.5) translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
          transform: scale(0.5) translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.95s, -webkit-transform 0.95s;
  transition: opacity 0.95s, -webkit-transform 0.95s;
  transition: transform 0.95s, opacity 0.95s;
  transition: transform 0.95s, opacity 0.95s, -webkit-transform 0.95s;
}
.el:nth-child(6) .el__inner {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
          transition-delay: 0s;

}
.el:nth-child(6) .el__bg {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
}
.el:nth-child(6) .el__inner:before {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
          transition-delay: 0s;
  background-image: url("../salvapantallas.jpg");
}
.cont.s--el-active .el:nth-child(5):not(.s--active) {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.5) translate3d(420.83333%, 0, 0);
          transform: scale(0.5) translate3d(420.83333%, 0, 0);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.95s, -webkit-transform 0.95s;
  transition: opacity 0.95s, -webkit-transform 0.95s;
  transition: transform 0.95s, opacity 0.95s;
  transition: transform 0.95s, opacity 0.95s, -webkit-transform 0.95s;
}
.el:nth-child(5) .el__inner {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.4s;
          transition-delay: 0.4s;
}
.el:nth-child(5) .el__bg {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-76.8%, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(-76.8%, 0, 0);
}
.el:nth-child(5) .el__bg:before {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.4s;
          transition-delay: 0.4s;
  background-image: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/142996/onepgscr-7.jpg");
}
.el:hover .el__bg:after {
  opacity: 0;
}
.el.s--active {
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transition: width 0.7s 0.7s, z-index 0s, -webkit-transform 0.6s;
  transition: width 0.7s 0.7s, z-index 0s, -webkit-transform 0.6s;
  transition: transform 0.6s, width 0.7s 0.7s, z-index 0s;
  transition: transform 0.6s, width 0.7s 0.7s, z-index 0s, -webkit-transform 0.6s;
}
.el.s--active .el__bg {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  transition: transform 0.6s, -webkit-transform 0.6s;
}
.el.s--active .el__bg:before {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.6s;
          transition-delay: 0.6s;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
          transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  
  
</head>

<body>
  <div class="cont s--inactive">
  <!-- cont inner start -->
  <div >
    <!-- el start -->
    <div class="el">
      <div class="el__overflow">
        <div class="el__inner">
         
          <div class="el__preview-cont">
            <div class="el__heading"> 
              <div class="imagen snip1273">
                 <figcaption>
                  <span>“</span>
                  <p>Nunc feugiat tempus enim.Nulla ipsum massa, portavel magna eu, dapibus efficitur eros.</p>
                  <img class="center-block img-responsive flecha" src="images/arrow-right.png">
                </figcaption> 
              </div>
              
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="el__content">
            <div class="el__text">
              <div class="img">
                
              </div>
              <div class="description">lorem dasd</div>
            </div>
            <div class="el__close-btn"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- el end -->
    <!-- el start -->
    <div class="el">
      <div class="el__overflow">
        <div class="el__inner">
         
          <div class="el__preview-cont" style="z-index: 22;position: absolute; top: 0; width: 250px;height: 401px;background: red;">
            <div class="el__heading"> 
              <img src="salvapantallas.jpg">
              <h2 style="position: absolute;top: 0;">mariano</h2>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="el__content">
            <div class="el__text">
              <div class="img">
                
              </div>
              <div class="description">lorem dasd</div>
            </div>
            <div class="el__close-btn"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- el end -->
    <!-- el start -->
    <div class="el">
      <div class="el__overflow">
        <div class="el__inner">
         
          <div class="el__preview-cont" style="z-index: 22;position: absolute; top: 0; width: 250px;height: 401px;background: red;">
            <div class="el__heading"> 
              <img src="salvapantallas.jpg">
              <h2 style="position: absolute;top: 0;">mariano</h2>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="el__content">
            <div class="el__text">
              <div class="img">
                
              </div>
              <div class="description">lorem dasd</div>
            </div>
            <div class="el__close-btn"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- el end -->
    <!-- el start -->
    <div class="el">
      <div class="el__overflow">
        <div class="el__inner">
         
          <div class="el__preview-cont" style="z-index: 22;position: absolute; top: 0; width: 250px;height: 401px;background: red;">
            <div class="el__heading"> 
              <img src="salvapantallas.jpg">
              <h2 style="position: absolute;top: 0;">mariano</h2>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="el__content">
            <div class="el__text">
              <div class="img">
                
              </div>
              <div class="description">lorem dasd</div>
            </div>
            <div class="el__close-btn"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- el end -->
    <!-- el start -->
    <div class="el">
      <div class="el__overflow">
        <div class="el__inner">
         
          <div class="el__preview-cont" style="z-index: 22;position: absolute; top: 0; width: 250px;height: 401px;background: red;">
            <div class="el__heading"> 
              <img src="salvapantallas.jpg">
              <h2 style="position: absolute;top: 0;">mariano</h2>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="el__content">
            <div class="el__text">
              <div class="img">
                
              </div>
              <div class="description">lorem dasd</div>
            </div>
            <div class="el__close-btn"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- el end -->
    <!-- el start -->
    <div class="el">
      <div class="el__overflow">
        <div class="el__inner">
         
          <div class="el__preview-cont" style="z-index: 22;position: absolute; top: 0; width: 250px;height: 401px;background: red;">
            <div class="el__heading"> 
              <img src="salvapantallas.jpg">
              <h2 style="position: absolute;top: 0;">mariano</h2>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="el__content">
            <div class="el__text">
              <div class="img">
                
              </div>
              <div class="description">lorem dasd</div>
            </div>
            <div class="el__close-btn"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- el end -->
  </div>
  <!-- cont inner end -->


</body>
</html>
```

para sacarlo cuando clickeo y me muestra el contenido de dicha ficha? le adjunto el ejemplo

Answer (score 0):

Buenas amigo espero esto sea lo que buscas

En el css agregue

```
.s--active .snip1273:hover figcaption,
.s--active .snip1273.hover figcaption {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

Cuando activas la imagen para ser visualizada le agregas una classe `.s--active`
 cuando la tenga que no muestre la descripción

Espero te ayude saludos

```js
var $cont = document.querySelector('.cont');
var $elsArr = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.el'));
var $closeBtnsArr = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.el__close-btn'));

setTimeout(function() {
  $cont.classList.remove('s--inactive');
}, 200);

$elsArr.forEach(function($el) {
  $el.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (this.classList.contains('s--active')) return;
    $cont.classList.add('s--el-active');
    this.classList.add('s--active');
  });
});

$closeBtnsArr.forEach(function($btn) {
  $btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $cont.classList.remove('s--el-active');
    document.querySelector('.el.s--active').classList.remove('s--active');
  });
});
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #1f1f1f;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.cont{
      width: 1170px;
    margin: auto;
    height: 404px;
    position: relative;
}

.el {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 15.999%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #252525;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.7s, opacity 0.6s 0.7s, z-index 0s 1.3s, -webkit-transform 0.6s 0.7s;
  transition: width 0.7s, opacity 0.6s 0.7s, z-index 0s 1.3s, -webkit-transform 0.6s 0.7s;
  transition: transform 0.6s 0.7s, width 0.7s, opacity 0.6s 0.7s, z-index 0s 1.3s;
  transition: transform 0.6s 0.7s, width 0.7s, opacity 0.6s 0.7s, z-index 0s 1.3s, -webkit-transform 0.6s 0.7s;
  will-change: transform, width, opacity;
}
.el:not(.s--active) {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.el__overflow {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
.el__inner {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
  transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
  transition: transform 1s;
  transition: transform 1s, -webkit-transform 1s;

}
.el__preview-cont{
  z-index: 22;
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  width: 250px;
  height: 401px;
}
.el__content {
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.1s;
  transition: all 0.1s;
}
.el.s--active .el__content {
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s 1.4s;
  transition: all 0.5s 1.4s;
}
.imagen{
background-image: url('../salvapantallas.jpg');
width: 405px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: 403px;

}




 .snip1273 {
  font-family: 'Raleway', Arial, sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
  min-width: 403px;
  max-width: 403px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 16px;
}
 .snip1273 * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
}
 .snip1273 img {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
 .snip1273 figcaption {
  position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 187px;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 77px 20px 0px 20px;
}
 .snip1273 figcaption .flecha{
  margin-top: 49px;
}
 .snip1273 figcaption:before,
 .snip1273 figcaption:after {
  width: 1px;
  height: 0;
}
 .snip1273 figcaption:before {
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
 .snip1273 figcaption:after {
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
 .snip1273 span,
 .snip1273 p {
  line-height: 1.5em;
}
 .snip1273 span {
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 71px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'helvetica';
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0;
    height: 76px;
    display: block;
}
 .snip1273 p {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
}
 .snip1273 a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
 .snip1273:before,
 .snip1273:after,
 .snip1273 figcaption:before,
 .snip1273 figcaption:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  background-color: #ffffff;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
  opacity: 0.8;
}


.snip1273:hover img,
 .snip1273.hover img {
  opacity: 0.4;
}
.snip1273:hover figcaption,
.snip1273.hover figcaption {
  opacity: 1;
}
/*codigo nuevo*/
 .s--active .snip1273:hover figcaption,
 .s--active .snip1273.hover figcaption {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility:hidden;
}
/*codigo nuevo*/
 .snip1273:hover:before,
  .snip1273.hover:before,
  .snip1273:hover:after,
  .snip1273.hover:after,
  .snip1273:hover figcaption:before,
  .snip1273.hover figcaption:before,
  .snip1273:hover figcaption:after,
  .snip1273.hover figcaption:after {
  opacity: 0.1;
}




.el__text .img {
    width: 403px;
    height: 402px;
    float: left;
}
.el__text .description{
    width: 765px;
    float: right;
    padding: 30px;
    height: 403px;
}
.el__text img{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 344px;
    min-width: 401px;
}
.el__close-btn {
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0s 0.45s;
  transition: all 0s 0.45s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.el.s--active .el__close-btn {
  z-index: 5;
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  -webkit-transition: all 0s 1.4s;
  transition: all 0s 1.4s;
}
.el__close-btn:before, .el__close-btn:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 8px;
  margin-top: -4px;
  background: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0s;
  transition: opacity 0s;
}
.el.s--active .el__close-btn:before, .el.s--active .el__close-btn:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
.el__close-btn:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translateX(100%);
          transform: rotate(45deg) translateX(100%);
}
.el.s--active .el__close-btn:before {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s 1.4s cubic-bezier(0.72, 0.09, 0.32, 1.57);
  transition: all 0.3s 1.4s cubic-bezier(0.72, 0.09, 0.32, 1.57);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translateX(0);
          transform: rotate(45deg) translateX(0);
}
.el__close-btn:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translateX(100%);
          transform: rotate(-45deg) translateX(100%);
}
.el.s--active .el__close-btn:after {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s 1.55s cubic-bezier(0.72, 0.09, 0.32, 1.57);
  transition: all 0.3s 1.55s cubic-bezier(0.72, 0.09, 0.32, 1.57);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translateX(0);
          transform: rotate(-45deg) translateX(0);
}

.el:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
          transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
.cont.s--el-active .el:nth-child(1):not(.s--active) {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.5) translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
          transform: scale(0.5) translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.95s, -webkit-transform 0.95s;
  transition: opacity 0.95s, -webkit-transform 0.95s;
  transition: transform 0.95s, opacity 0.95s;
  transition: transform 0.95s, opacity 0.95s, -webkit-transform 0.95s;
}
.el:nth-child(1) .el__inner {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
          transition-delay: 0s;

}
.el:nth-child(1) .el__bg {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
}
.el:nth-child(1) .el__inner:before {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
          transition-delay: 0s;
  background-image: url("../salvapantallas.jpg");
}
.el:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(105.20833%, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(105.20833%, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 155.20833% 50%;
          transform-origin: 155.20833% 50%;
}
.cont.s--el-active .el:nth-child(2):not(.s--active) {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.5) translate3d(105.20833%, 0, 0);
          transform: scale(0.5) translate3d(105.20833%, 0, 0);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.95s, -webkit-transform 0.95s;
  transition: opacity 0.95s, -webkit-transform 0.95s;
  transition: transform 0.95s, opacity 0.95s;
  transition: transform 0.95s, opacity 0.95s, -webkit-transform 0.95s;
}
.el:nth-child(2) .el__inner {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s;
          transition-delay: 0.1s;
}
.el:nth-child(2) .el__bg {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-19.2%, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(-19.2%, 0, 0);
}
.el:nth-child(2) .el__bg:before {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s;
          transition-delay: 0.1s;
  background-image: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/142996/onepgscr-4.jpg");
}
.el:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(210.41667%, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(210.41667%, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 260.41667% 50%;
          transform-origin: 260.41667% 50%;
}
.cont.s--el-active .el:nth-child(3):not(.s--active) {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.5) translate3d(210.41667%, 0, 0);
          transform: scale(0.5) translate3d(210.41667%, 0, 0);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.95s, -webkit-transform 0.95s;
  transition: opacity 0.95s, -webkit-transform 0.95s;
  transition: transform 0.95s, opacity 0.95s;
  transition: transform 0.95s, opacity 0.95s, -webkit-transform 0.95s;
}
.el:nth-child(3) .el__inner {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
          transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
.el:nth-child(3) .el__bg {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-38.4%, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(-38.4%, 0, 0);
}
.el:nth-child(3) .el__bg:before {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
          transition-delay: 0.2s;
  background-image: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/142996/onepgscr-5.jpg");
}
.el:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(315.625%, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(315.625%, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 365.625% 50%;
          transform-origin: 365.625% 50%;
}
.cont.s--el-active .el:nth-child(4):not(.s--active) {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.5) translate3d(315.625%, 0, 0);
          transform: scale(0.5) translate3d(315.625%, 0, 0);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.95s, -webkit-transform 0.95s;
  transition: opacity 0.95s, -webkit-transform 0.95s;
  transition: transform 0.95s, opacity 0.95s;
  transition: transform 0.95s, opacity 0.95s, -webkit-transform 0.95s;
}
.el:nth-child(4) .el__inner {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s;
          transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
.el:nth-child(4) .el__bg {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-57.6%, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(-57.6%, 0, 0);
}
.el:nth-child(4) .el__bg:before {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s;
          transition-delay: 0.3s;
  background-image: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/142996/onepgscr-6.jpg");
}
.el:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(420.83333%, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(420.83333%, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 470.83333% 50%;
          transform-origin: 470.83333% 50%;
}


.el:nth-child(6) {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(527%, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(527%, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 527% 50%;
          transform-origin: 527% 50%;
}
.cont.s--el-active .el:nth-child(6):not(.s--active) {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.5) translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
          transform: scale(0.5) translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.95s, -webkit-transform 0.95s;
  transition: opacity 0.95s, -webkit-transform 0.95s;
  transition: transform 0.95s, opacity 0.95s;
  transition: transform 0.95s, opacity 0.95s, -webkit-transform 0.95s;
}
.el:nth-child(6) .el__inner {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
          transition-delay: 0s;

}
.el:nth-child(6) .el__bg {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
}
.el:nth-child(6) .el__inner:before {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
          transition-delay: 0s;
  background-image: url("../salvapantallas.jpg");
}
.cont.s--el-active .el:nth-child(5):not(.s--active) {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.5) translate3d(420.83333%, 0, 0);
          transform: scale(0.5) translate3d(420.83333%, 0, 0);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.95s, -webkit-transform 0.95s;
  transition: opacity 0.95s, -webkit-transform 0.95s;
  transition: transform 0.95s, opacity 0.95s;
  transition: transform 0.95s, opacity 0.95s, -webkit-transform 0.95s;
}
.el:nth-child(5) .el__inner {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.4s;
          transition-delay: 0.4s;
}
.el:nth-child(5) .el__bg {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-76.8%, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(-76.8%, 0, 0);
}
.el:nth-child(5) .el__bg:before {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.4s;
          transition-delay: 0.4s;
  background-image: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/142996/onepgscr-7.jpg");
}
.el:hover .el__bg:after {
  opacity: 0;
}
.el.s--active {
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transition: width 0.7s 0.7s, z-index 0s, -webkit-transform 0.6s;
  transition: width 0.7s 0.7s, z-index 0s, -webkit-transform 0.6s;
  transition: transform 0.6s, width 0.7s 0.7s, z-index 0s;
  transition: transform 0.6s, width 0.7s 0.7s, z-index 0s, -webkit-transform 0.6s;
}
.el.s--active .el__bg {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  transition: transform 0.6s, -webkit-transform 0.6s;
}
.el.s--active .el__bg:before {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.6s;
          transition-delay: 0.6s;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
          transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  
  
</head>

<body>
  <div class="cont s--inactive">
  <!-- cont inner start -->
  <div >
    <!-- el start -->
    <div class="el">
      <div class="el__overflow">
        <div class="el__inner">
         
          <div class="el__preview-cont">
            <div class="el__heading"> 
              <div class="imagen snip1273">
                 <figcaption>
                  <span>“</span>
                  <p>Nunc feugiat tempus enim.Nulla ipsum massa, portavel magna eu, dapibus efficitur eros.</p>
                  <img class="center-block img-responsive flecha" src="images/arrow-right.png">
                </figcaption> 
              </div>
              
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="el__content">
            <div class="el__text">
              <div class="img">
                
              </div>
              <div class="description">lorem dasd</div>
            </div>
            <div class="el__close-btn"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- el end -->
    <!-- el start -->
    <div class="el">
      <div class="el__overflow">
        <div class="el__inner">
         
          <div class="el__preview-cont" style="z-index: 22;position: absolute; top: 0; width: 250px;height: 401px;background: red;">
            <div class="el__heading"> 
              <img src="salvapantallas.jpg">
              <h2 style="position: absolute;top: 0;">mariano</h2>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="el__content">
            <div class="el__text">
              <div class="img">
                
              </div>
              <div class="description">lorem dasd</div>
            </div>
            <div class="el__close-btn"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- el end -->
    <!-- el start -->
    <div class="el">
      <div class="el__overflow">
        <div class="el__inner">
         
          <div class="el__preview-cont" style="z-index: 22;position: absolute; top: 0; width: 250px;height: 401px;background: red;">
            <div class="el__heading"> 
              <img src="salvapantallas.jpg">
              <h2 style="position: absolute;top: 0;">mariano</h2>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="el__content">
            <div class="el__text">
              <div class="img">
                
              </div>
              <div class="description">lorem dasd</div>
            </div>
            <div class="el__close-btn"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- el end -->
    <!-- el start -->
    <div class="el">
      <div class="el__overflow">
        <div class="el__inner">
         
          <div class="el__preview-cont" style="z-index: 22;position: absolute; top: 0; width: 250px;height: 401px;background: red;">
            <div class="el__heading"> 
              <img src="salvapantallas.jpg">
              <h2 style="position: absolute;top: 0;">mariano</h2>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="el__content">
            <div class="el__text">
              <div class="img">
                
              </div>
              <div class="description">lorem dasd</div>
            </div>
            <div class="el__close-btn"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- el end -->
    <!-- el start -->
    <div class="el">
      <div class="el__overflow">
        <div class="el__inner">
         
          <div class="el__preview-cont" style="z-index: 22;position: absolute; top: 0; width: 250px;height: 401px;background: red;">
            <div class="el__heading"> 
              <img src="salvapantallas.jpg">
              <h2 style="position: absolute;top: 0;">mariano</h2>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="el__content">
            <div class="el__text">
              <div class="img">
                
              </div>
              <div class="description">lorem dasd</div>
            </div>
            <div class="el__close-btn"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- el end -->
    <!-- el start -->
    <div class="el">
      <div class="el__overflow">
        <div class="el__inner">
         
          <div class="el__preview-cont" style="z-index: 22;position: absolute; top: 0; width: 250px;height: 401px;background: red;">
            <div class="el__heading"> 
              <img src="salvapantallas.jpg">
              <h2 style="position: absolute;top: 0;">mariano</h2>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="el__content">
            <div class="el__text">
              <div class="img">
                
              </div>
              <div class="description">lorem dasd</div>
            </div>
            <div class="el__close-btn"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- el end -->
  </div>
  <!-- cont inner end -->


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias @luis Daniel Rovira Contreras, sos un genio!!!

Comment: De nada amigo si la Respuesta es correcta por favor dale como respondida para que la comunidad sepa saludos y espero te ayude

Comment: Te hago una ultima pregunta si no es mucha molestia y complicación, no se si probaste el ejemplo con una imagen adjunta, te explico cada fila tiene una imagen de fondo que cuando pasas el mouse por arriba hace el hover, esa imagen que muestra al comienzo seria como un pedazo de una imagen mas grande, ahora bien cuando clickeas debería mostrarse al 100% de la caja que la contiene osea a la mitad cuando esta expandida la caja, nose si me explico. te adjunto el link del proyecto con una foto que agregue yo que seria la original http://qkstudiodemo.com/radiocantilo/html/

Comment: Creo mas o menos entenderte, la imagen que tienes que usar debe tener el tamaño del ancho final osea despues de darle click pero cuando todavia no le has dado que tenga un contenedor con `overflow:hidden` de un `width` del tamaño deseado osea (200px) y cuando le das `click` ese contenedor se pone al `100%` y la imagen se vera completa

Comment: Claro! si eso mismo voy a probar

Comment: Excelente amigo